# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I really don't know what's the problem, I always get this error when I try to build my project

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0] C:\Users\AYOUB\Desktop\Boiling ball studio\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage

Comment: one of your dependencies has declared minSdkVersion = 14, so your project need to have minSdkVersion at least 14 to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error; you should update your minimum version from 11 to 14.

Google Play services need at least Android version 14 (4.0) to work.

[Check this link from Google](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: This solution worked for me. In build.gradle I just set the minSDK to 14 and re-built it.  defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 14
}

Answer (score 0):

Manifest Merger occurs when there is a mismatch in a version of your dependencies. So be careful to mention the version of your dependencies to be same.
And also make sure that the version is same in all the external libraries or a module, you are using.